# PHP: Using a function to print content vs returning the content as a variable and then printing that instead

Tags: php, function, templates, printing

I have some classes to do things for a website like get news, create a discography of recordings, gig listings etc. There are functions for listGigs(), listHeadlines() etc and these print out the relevant info to the screen.

Is there a drawback to having a function return all the html as a variable and then printing this variable later instead of printing it out directly through a function call?

If I can set up all the content for each page in generic variables e.g. $maincontent then I can call these in a html template. It seems straight forward enough, I'm just wondering if this is good practice or not. Here is the general plan of what I am talking about anyway:

in the php file

```
$maincontent = $news->getHeadlines;
include_once 'template.php';
```

in the template file

```
<body>
    <div>Some stuff</div>
    <div clas="main"><?php echo $maincontent; ?></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issue with creating direct to output widgets. If you wanted to be afforded a little more flexibility though you could implement something like this

```
function displayTemplate($template, $data, $__captureOutput = false){
    if ($__captureOutput) ob_start();
    extract ($data);
    include($template);
    if ($__captureOutput) return ob_get_clean();
}
```

and for your above use case you would just do either

```
$maincontent = $news->getHeadlines;
displayTemplate('template.php',array("maincontent"=>$maincontent));
```

or

```
$maincontent = $news->getHeadlines;
$data = displayTemplate('template.php',array("maincontent"=>$maincontent), true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd question whether even returning HTML from the function would be wise.

The drawback of having the function output HTML is you've now coupled application (domain) logic with presentation logic.  Suppose you want to present the same data in a different way, such as a JSON object or raw data to write to a file.  You'd either have to write additional functions for each case or write a function that will parse the HTML, extract the data from it and convert it to the format you want.

If the function does the work but only returns a PHP data structure, then you can use that output as the input to another function that implements the presentation logic.

Printing HTML directly from the function is really inflexible, and you won't even have the option to reparse it into another format.

Good software is, as a rule, loosely coupled with the various concerns separated from each other.  Computation of data and presentation of data are separate concerns.

Comment: Oops, wasn't finished that... 
By php data structure do you mean an array? In this case the class files create an array from a database so that is there already in the object (if i understand these concepts correctly...), and then this function is to convert that to html. I don't see how I could create json or anything else without another function to do it.